# How to import Multibit HD Wallet in bcoin?

Tags: private-key, multibit-hd, mnemonic-seed, bcoin

I created a wallet using Multibit HD and noted the mnemonic. I sent some money to an address that showed up in Multibit HD. Worked fine. Transaktions are displayed and balance is adjusted. Can be verified on blockchain.info for example.

Using the [Mnemonic Code Converter](https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/) I derived the BIP32 Extended Private Key. With the REST-API of bcoin I both created a wallet using the mnemonic and using the private key. After that I did a rescan at height 0.

Now I would expect that my accounts both have the same balance as in Multibit HD, but both have zero balance and zero transaktions.

What did I do wrong?

---

- The bcoin node is fully synced and has progress 1.
- Both bcoin and Multibit are using Mainnet.
- Both Wallets show the same master key (the one that was derived on the website). Only the one created by the mnemonic also displays that mnemonic.

During research I already found out that the address used for the transaktion only shows up on [Mnemonic Code Converter](https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/) if I choose Multibit HD as the Client under the BIP32-Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultiBit HD uses a BIP 32 derivation path that is different from basically all other wallet implementations. MultiBit HD's derivation path is `m/0'/0/i` whereas most wallets use derivation paths set by BIP 44 which is `m/44'/0'/0'/0/i`. So when getting addresses from a MultiBit HD seed, you will need to use MultiBit HD's derivation path instead of the default BIP 44 one used by most wallet software.

Comment: Is it possible to set up a wallet with the Multibit path using bcoin? Or ist is even possible to set up a wallet that "monitors" multiple paths?